# Running am commands in terminal without using su

Tags: terminal

Android: JB 4.2.2

I am trying to launch Android apps from the terminal emulator using the `am` command. When I tried the phone's terminal emulator application, it gave me an error:-

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:1906)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:494)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:109)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:82)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I go into root mode, then the am command works. Any idea how to get `am` to launch browser without doing an `su` in the terminal emulator?

Comment: Hi, actually when i use "am" without root the err msg is: Permissio denied, app requested to run as user 2 but calling from user 0. I ggogled this, google results have the exact same err msg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the `--user 0` option to your `am` command.

Comment: Hello, your solution worked perfectly. thank you very much, u see until now i was wooried that all my android apps were being launched by "am" as root. I hope that is not the case right now?

Comment: No, that's not the case. The "user" in the command-line refers to Jelly Bean's user profiles, not to Unix user IDs. When you're using a terminal session, you need to specify which user profile the app should be running in.

Comment: understood. thnx again

Comment: Very interesting comment. I until now assumed that the user in terminal emulator doesn't have sufficient privileges to use `am` command.

Comment: I got bad component name : --user

Comment: @Milad Either you're using an Android version older than Jelly Bean, or you put the option in the wrong place. If you need more help, ask a new question and give your Android version and the exact command you're typing.

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to start service from terminal and i got similar output. 
In my case  i just added qoutation marks and that helped.

su -c 'am startservice -n "com.example.app/.YourSe-rvice" -e "extra' "value"'